# How do I count the occurrence of elements in a list using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, count

I have an 'object' type column in my dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to convert this to a list and count the occurence of each word by doing:

[image]

I want my output to look like this instead:

### counts

winter squash - 1

mexican seasoning - 1

mixed spice - 1

---

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pandas function built exactly for that:

```
df2['ingredients'].explode().value_counts()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This gives me the count of each list. I am looking for the count of each element within the list.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't realize that it was a column of lists. I've edited the answer.